# ASP.NET drop down list filtered by JavaScript + button postback error

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I have an asp.net drop down list that has a number of items, users are allowed to type some text into an asp.net textbox and javascript will filter the data in the drop down list. This all works perfectly until the user enters text that matches no item. When this occurs I create a new option in javascript with "no XXX found" with a value of "0". The user the clicks an asp.net button and the page errors.

The error message i'm getting is:

> Invalid postback or callback argument. Event validation is enabled using `<pages enableEventValidation="true"/>` in configuration or `<%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %>` in a page. For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them. If the data is valid and expected, use the `ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation` method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation.

Setting this to true does nothing, and I can't figure out why the page would fall over on the postback.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `EnableEventValidation="false"` will fix the problem, but open up the page to security holes.

To solve the problem without causing security holes, call `ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation`.  For more details, please show us your code.

Answer (score 0):

Tried messing around with all of that but with no luck, here's a cut down version of my code:

```
List<ListItem> items = new List<ListItem>();
items.Add(new ListItem("abc", "1");
items.Add(new ListItem("xyz", "1");

foreach (ListItem item in items)
{
    ddlCompanies.Items.Add(item);
}
```

Javascript on a textboxs onkeyup event:

```
function filter() {
    var pattern = document.getElementById('<%= tbFilterText.ClientID %>').value;
    var dropDownList = document.getElementById('<%= ddlCompanies.ClientID  %>');

    if (pattern != null && dropDownList != null) {

        /* 
        *   Check if the dropdown list has been backed up before 
        */
        if (!dropDownList.bak) {
            /*
            *   Backup the current items in the dropdown list
            */
            dropDownList.bak = new Array();
            for (n = 0; n < dropDownList.length; n++) {
                dropDownList.bak[dropDownList.bak.length]
= new Array(dropDownList[n].value, dropDownList[n].text);
            }
        }

        /*
        *    Loop through the backed up dropdown list and find matches
        *    for the pattern text. 
        */
        matches = new Array();
        for (n = 0; n < dropDownList.bak.length; n++) {
            if (dropDownList.bak[n][1].toLowerCase().indexOf(pattern.toLowerCase()) != -1) {
                matches[matches.length] = new Array(dropDownList.bak[n][0], dropDownList.bak[n][1]);
            }
        }

        dropDownList.options.length = 0;

        //Add the matched items to the dropDownList
        for (n = 0; n < matches.length; n++) {
            dropDownList.options[n] = new Option(matches[n][1], matches[n][0]);
        }

        // If no companies could be found then display a placeholder option
        if (dropDownList.options.length == 0) {
            dropDownList.options[0] = new Option(document.getElementById('Nothing found').value, "-1");
        }

        dropDownList.selectedIndex = 0;
    }
}
```

Then a button click which should cause a postback causes the error